# Accessing folder is very slow

Tags: windows

I have some more than 100 exe files in a folder. I have enough RAM(4GB). Every other tasks in my system works just fine when I open this particular folder the the explorer doesn't respond. I scanned the folder and my system for virus. I don't have virus [as per result by McAfee, Kaspersky and Windows defender]. I have no clue what may be possible cause for this?

Comment: probable guess would be bad sectors

Comment: @Sathya: Just got a new hard drive. 2 days ago only.

Comment: doesn't mean new hard drives can't contain bad sectors

Comment: how to check for bad sectors?

Comment: Do you have McAfee, Kaspersky and Windows Defender all running at the same time? Maybe that is what is causing the slowness. It's generally considered not to be a good idea to be running more than one virus checker at the same time.

Comment: @dangph: No I don;t have multiple antivirus at a time. In some forum I have read changing the antivirus will detect most of the virus. So I have tried with different antivirus.

Comment: See if [this](http://superuser.com/a/240623/138343) helps. If not, the slowdown is most likely due to your AV scanning every EXE when you access the folder. To confirm, disconnect from the net and temporarily uninstall your AV and also ensure (depending on your Windows version) that Defender's service is turned off. Does the folder display much faster now?

Comment: @Dibya, Karan's idea is good. You could also try making a copy of the folder and see if the copy is also slow. Then try removing files and see what happens.