# Windows 7 is very slow opening some directories

Tags: windows-7, windows

For the last few weeks my test computer at work takes very long time to display directories.

The problem can be seen at least in explorer.exe and in the open file dialog windows of some programs (like notepad++.exe).

The problem seems to be more visible when directory to open contains several dll files.

I do not have the problem from command line.

This computer is not connected to the Internet, its antivirus is deactived most of the time, but I run it to test if the problem could come from a virus (without success).

I try to change folder view settings without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the hard drive or with the file system. Use ckhdsk to check the file system and HDDScan to test the surface.

Comment: I have that effect when I add more columns to the explorer view, for example 'Date taken' (which is useful for photos). Even after removing the column again, the display of the directory takes often 20 seconds (for less than 50 files); it seems that windows remembers (incorrectly) that it needs to look at the extended data of each file.

Comment: @Hardoman The effect is visible on local drive, on usb key or on network shares, the same key or share are not impacted on windows xp or linux.

Comment: It's normal, that if HDD is affected, you'll have slow access to the other drives, including USB, as when accessing them, Windows is still utilizing system libraries/dll that it reads from the HDD. You mean that Windows XP and Linux are working fine on the same PC running from the same HDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem corrected, I try something near from https://superuser.com/a/240623/369294:

1. open your buggy folder
2. right click in a white space and go to properties
3. select the tab "Customize"
4. in the dropdownlist of "Optimize this folder for:"
   select **"Documents"**